# Nintex workflow to change user group?

Tags: sharepoint, permissions, workflow

I am currently trying to set up a nintex workflow in SP 2010 that will run when an item is created in a list. Basically, users will be set in a custom permissions group before they create an item. When an item is created, the workflow will check for who created the item and then set that person in a different custom permissions group. From what I have found, the only way to do this is by using a call web service action, this requires credentials that I do not have access to. I was curious if there was a way to achieve the same permissions switch workflow without using the call web service action?

Answer (score 0):

You could always use the action "change item permission" which should do the trick for modifying permissions to the item. you can assign it to either a person or group.

I would also suggest looking at a different route for managing item permissions. Change them at the item level is doable but can quickly become a nightmare if you want to revert things or figure out who has what after the 1000th item has been modified.

Comment: Thanks for the response Eric, I don't need to modify the permissions of the items in the list. The permissions are to restrict access to certain webparts and pages in the site. I just need the workflow to kick off specifically when a person creates an item within the list.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/12598524)

Comment: @MLavoie - I would suggest you look at the answer again. It was two parts because part of it was subjective from the question and I did provide an actionable answer by using the change item permission action as an alternative. That specifically answers the question; however because this software, like many others are subjective, its a discussion on method, not a matter of function.